# Searching for an English Whats-app Corpus

Tags: english, corpora, written-language

I am searching an English Whats-app Corpus in order to analyse a linguistic phenomena. I had some difficulties to find one and maybe some of you can help me out. It is only for corpus driven study and also not such a big one. Thus it does not has to be a very large corpus.

It is to fulfill these criteria:

- of English language
- free for use
- at least 1000 messages
- downloadable

Manby someone here can help me with this. I already like to thank in advance for taking the time.

Comment: I am looking for the exact same thing, therefore I was wondering if you (or anyone else) by now found such a corpus.

Answer (score 1):

Fixating on whatsapp restricts the choices pretty much, so one might consider other social media and platforms as well for Computer Mediated Communication. However, a standard approach to find some corpora is using the Virtual Language Observatory (VLO) hosted by CLARIN ERIC

https://vlo.clarin.eu

an search for "whatsapp". Restricting the language to "English" in the facetted search gives currently exactly one hit, namely "Linguistic Aspects of Texting and its Influence on Cognitive and Social Development" hosted at DANS:

https://easy.dans.knaw.nl/ui/datasets/id/easy-dataset:63044